# Hiberante mapping

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I have this tables [image]

So my entities:

```
public class Protocol{
      private Long id;
      private LocaDateTime day;
      private List<?> object;
}    

  public class Car{
      private Long id;
      private Long protocoloId;
      private LocalDate year;
      private String color;
    }

    public class Home{
      private Long id;
      private Long protocoloId;
      private String address;
      private String type;
      private int year;
    }
```

And in taht db I have

Assuming that for the id 1 in the protocol table I have 2 record in the Car table and for the id 2  I have 1 record in the Home table

It`s possible to when I select the Protocolo 1 the hibernate(or springboot) return in propert OBJECT the corresponding data by protocol type (property 'type')

tks

I using springboot

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you have more understanding about Model classes in Spring-boot. You can have a look on [JPA Entities](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entities). If you need to get the full object, you should define a reference object which points out other class

Eg: `private Protocol protocoloId;`

I've defined some annotation which may be needed based on how you define the table in your database. Sometimes you define more annotations to map the entity to class to your table( Eg : `@Column`, `@Tabel`... etc)

```
@Entity
public class Protocol{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private LocaDateTime day;
    private List<?> object;

    //No argument constructors & argument constructors
    // Getters and setters
}    

@Entity
public class Car{
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="protocol_id")
    private Protocol protocoloId;
    private LocalDate year;
    private String color;

    //No argument constructors & argument constructors
    // Getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Home{
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="protocol_id")
    private Protocol protocoloId;

    private String address;
    private String type;
    private int year;

    //No argument constructors & argument constructors
    // Getters and setters
}
```

Comment: tks to help, but I know how to map entities in hibernate, I only omit the annotations, to explain the all problem :D that are if I can map 1 propertie to mora than one table

Comment: I thought, you are the beginner(havent mentioned you omitted annotations :D). Thts ok, but u can get the objext by using reference like I said